# Escape comma in "$@" expansion

Tags: bash, shell

`"$@"` seems to make `,` disappear. e.g.

```
param="123 1,2"
set echo $param
"$@"
```

This will echo "123 1 2" instead of "123 1,2", but in some cases `,` is needed as a value to a command.

And this seems to be related to bash version, with bash 4.1.2, the result is correct, but with 4.2.46, the comma is missing.

---

Edit:

In short, maybe it's `nice` to blame:

I did `unset IFS` and in terminal the test case I gave worked correctly, but not with my script.

I'm actually working on an init script, I checked the `action()` function in `/etc/init.d/functions`, and added some debugging code:

```
echo "$@" # added by me
unset IFS # added by me
"$@" && success $"$STRING" || failure $"$STRING"
```

the command echoed is correct(`nice -n -10 ovs-vswitchd ... --socket-mem 1024,1024`), but in the `ps` result the actual command executed by nice becomes `ovs-vswitchd ... --socket-mem 1024 1024`.

I started to think maybe it's `nice` to blame.

Comment: Check the IFS on the one it is broken on.

Comment: This seems like a bug in bash 4.1. I am checking the [changelog for bash 4.2](https://github.com/sunny256/bash/blob/master/CWRU/changelog) to see if there is something related.

Comment: Its working fine with version 4.2.47 ...

Comment: It works fine with bash 4.2.46 on RHEL 7.

Comment: GNU bash v4.3.42 reporting in, also working. To me it seems like the IFS is not set to default

Comment: @123 I tried to unset IFS and updated my question

Comment: Wrap the arg in single quotes?

Comment: `set -- "$param"` should fix your problem

Comment: Your test case works fine; can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the behaviour with`nice`?

Comment: Which _*nix_ distro?  (_Cyrus_'s comment says `bash` *v4.2.46* on *RHEL 7* is OK, so maybe there's some distro-specific modification at work.)

Comment: `echo "$@"` isn't actually usefully representative of what's really being run -- you can't tell the difference between `echo "foo bar"` and `echo foo bar`. Instead, `printf '%q ' "$@"; printf '\n'`

Comment: On a RH 6.9 it seems to work just fine:
# env | grep -i lang
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
# param="123 1,2"
# set echo $param
# "$@"
123 1,2

The ',' didn't get eaten up. Could it be something to do with locale settings ?

Comment: No, `nice` isn't "to blame" at all -- it passes its argv through literally. `ps` doesn't tell you anything useful about where quotes are; it doesn't reflect quotes in its output, so you can't tell if a program was started with correct quoting by reviewing `ps` output.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the IFS directly in your script just before splitting param (before command `set`). For example do something like this:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
param="123 1,2"
IFS=" "  # put tabs and or newline if also wanted.
set echo $param
IFS=$oldIFS
"$@"
```

This will work no matter what was your IFS before.

Comment: If the OP wants to do string-splitting, the best practice is to use `read -a`, not to depend on IFS at all. `IFS= read -r -a args <<<"$param"; set -- echo "${args[@]}"` modifies `IFS` only for the duration of the `read` command, so you don't need to restore and return the old value

Comment: ...which is important, because the `oldIFS` approach is buggy: In the case where the old value is unset (`unset IFS`), then the code above will result in materially different behavior before and after.

Comment: Always wrap `$IFS` in quotes. So, always do it like `oldIFS="$IFS"`.